# Selecting filename and moving to corresponding folders from bat file

Tags: batch-file

The problem is I have a folder say D:/xyz the folder contains file1.DAT file2.DAT and folders of the same name as .DAT files that is folders file1 and file2.

I want a bat file which will read the filename of .DAT files and move the .DAT files to corresponding folders that is file1.DAT to file1 folder and file2.DAT to file2 folder.

Plz help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d /b *.DAT') do echo move "%%i" "%%~ni\%%i"
```

Remove the `echo`, if you are satisfied with the output.

EDIT:

explanation of the `dir`parameters:

`/a-d`: `A`ttribute: `-`not `d`irectory

`/b` show full path/name, but no size, no date, no header, no summary

(for more help see `dir /?`)

I also changed to support long filenames (according to foxidrive) and changed `copy`to `move`, as your question requires.

Comment: Thanxs Stephan it solved my problem. This was very help full, It would be great if u can explain wat /a-d /b this does.